# Why doesn't my newly-installed .Net Windows service make updates to its database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-services

I wrote a Windows service in .Net and had it successfully running on a server.  I don't recall all the steps that were performed in terms of permissions on the old server, which is what I think I am missing on the new one.

On the new server, in Visual Studio, I can run the service, it updates the database database.

The service also updates its own Windows event log.

When I launch the Windows service, I see it's event log updated indicating the service has started, however there are no database updates made.

I'm wondering if there are some permissions that need to be set for this to occur.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just to be clear: this is happening on the same machine? The only difference is that it's failing to write to the database when being run as a Service?

Comment: You're probably right. It's unlikely that the actual service is running under the same user context as the Visual Studio debugger. Find which context your service is running under and grant permission, or change the user account your service uses to one that already has permission and try again.

Comment: Are you running via a scheduled task or a true service?  I run a lot of scheduled tasks and have run into this.  In that circumstance, I had to open task scheduler, open the properties of the task, select 'Run whether user is logged on or not' and 'Run with highest privileges'.  In addition, on the same tab (General) there's an option to choose what user account to use when running the task, which needs to be set to something with appropriate permissions.  I'm guessing the same three options are available whether you are using service or scheduled task, and all need to be set appropriately.

Comment: [MSDN Specify Security Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x72fzyf(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I suggest that you add logging into your service so that you can debug these kinds of issues when your service is running outside of Visual Studio. I always find this to be essential when I am creating a Windows service.